# Cython C++ Cache - How to Clear

Tags: python, c++, jupyter-notebook, cython

I am running a Jupyter notebook on a remote server. Part of this notebook calls a Cython `.pyx` file `cython_file` which contains a c++ function definition called `cpp_function` and is called from the notebook like this:

`from clibs.cython_file import cpp_function`

Inside the `.pyx` file I am calling a c++ header file `cpp_file.h` like this:

`cdef extern from "/home/user/cpp_file.h":`

Inside this header file I have the function as defined in cython which, for argument sake, is just a simple logic function.

My issue is this; sometimes when I change the `.h` c++ file and restart the notebook kernel and re-run the code, nothing changes. It still uses the old version of the `.h` file. As if it's being cached somewhere.

I have deleted all `.pyxbldc` and `.pyc` files before restarting the kernel to no avail.

My `.pyxbld` file looks like this:

```
def make_ext(modname, pyxfilename):
    from distutils.extension import Extension
    return Extension(name=modname,
                     sources=[pyxfilename], extra_compile_args=['-fopenmp', '-w'], extra_link_args=['-fopenmp'], language='c++')
```

Any ideas on how to stop the c++ file from being cached?!

Comment: Running Jupyter and Cython locally, I find that I can force recompilation by deleting Cython's cache. On macOS, the default location appears to be `~/.ipython/cython`, so I run `rm -rf ~/.ipython/cython` every time I change Cython code in my Jupyter notebook. I'm not sure how to extend this solution for your situation, but maybe that'll get you started.

Comment: @wkschwartz Any idea where the cython cache is located in linux, specifically Ubuntu?

Comment: @RestInPeace Try `/home/<user_name>/.cache/ipython/cython`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't stop the C++ file from being cached, but you can clear the cache before running the `%%cython` cell magic.

```
!rm -rf ~/.cache/ipython/cython
```

Comment: @shaedrich Please pay attention when reviewing. This is not a link-only answer. It is a poor answer which could do with some additional explanation, but it is an answer nonetheless.